# Matlab handling values after getting them in edit text

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I have a little GUI, built with the MATLAB guide. It has a few edit text, where i set the values of my parameters. After clicking the "run" button at the bottom, a function should be called with the parameters, that are set in those edit texts. What is the easiest way to do that? Im not sure about accessing the data.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Greets, R93

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MATLAB will generate a callback function for your "run" button in the m-file of your GUI:

```
function yourpushbutton_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
```

where `handles` is a structure containing all handles of the GUI. You can get the parameters from the `edit text` fields and call your function in this callback function. To get the text, use

```
text = get(handles.edittext1,'String');
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out that i could set it with

```
maxRPM = str2double(get(hObject,'String'));
set(handles.editMaxRPM, 'Double', maxRPM);
```